# How to automatically write html structure

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code .I have the php extension installed already . But it is very repetitive to create each php file with the base structure like this one . Since it does'nt automatically insert it for me .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<HTML lang="en">
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE></TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there anyway or short key to quickly copy this structure into the newly created php file ? without using control+C control+V from a note ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are using VS code then you can use this command `shift` + `1` and enter to auto-populate HTML Doctype in HTML or PHP.

[image]

When you will press enter it will add the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

1. press---> Shift+1 + enter or tab

OR

2. press---->  html:5 + enter or tab

Note:- In VS-Code.

Answer (score 11):

In VS Code,

Type ! and then press Enter

Comment: Copy of answer below from 2 years before

Answer (score 7):

Type `!`, and then click the first snippet in the auto complete. It will generate the default HTML template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, you can use snippet to add your own code, and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) should help you

Answer (score 2):

In a `.php` file, just type `!` at the beginning of the line and then hit the `tab` key ... you then get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why. just ! doesn't work for me, but when I type html5 or html:5 and use autocomplition,  it works like a charm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Type ! and then press enter

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) extension for these kind of things.

For example in a file with `.html` extension you start typing `html` and from pop up choose `html:5`